# Object hierarchical call in JAVA

Tags: java, class, hierarchy

I have a question regarding the Object hierarchical call.

I have four classes namely A, B, C, D.

D will be set in C; C will be in B; B will be in A.

If I want to do something in class D, I have to call a.b.c.d.setWidth("50%");(a, b, c, d are instance of Class A, B, C, d).

Is that fine to call like that? Will that compromise the performance?

Comment: What? It violates a few OO principles (namely data hiding), but it's probably fine performance wise and in theory.

Comment: Curiosity suck sometimes..

Comment: I also notice you've decided to eschew packages... don't do that.

Comment: First make it work, then make it right, then make it fast. Knuth's law just says don't skip steps 1 and 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect on performance will be very slight... the bigger issue is what that does to your object-oriented model.

Having direct access to the members of a class is frowned apon, and you are running risks of NullPointerExceptions.

What you should be more worried about is the readability and maintainability of your code.

Comment: Yeah. I am worrying about the readability and moreover null pointer exceptions.

Comment: What I thought is, I will be having many variables inside each class. I didn't want to create get/set for all the variables.

Comment: At least I can create it for the variables used often.

Comment: You should use proper OOP Encapsulation, and use an IDE like Eclipse/IntelliJ,/IDEA, and it will make the get*/set* methods for you. Don't be lazy!

Comment: Yeah. Now I can understand that i made a big blunder. Forgive me gosling.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly legal to call like that. I dnt think it will have performance issues.
But the design is not good.
You should use getters and setters inside the code.
For example :
In your case : `a.getB().getC().getD().setWidth("50%")`.

In class A , declare variable of B as private and similarly with class B and C.
It will ensure data hiding and encapsulation principles of an Object Oriented design.

Comment: If it will not affect the performance then I will do as you say.

Comment: There's nothing related to performance here. Its about your requirement. If you have such a requirement how would you call the setWidth method corresponding to d object declared in C class declared in B and so on. This is the way of calling. It is know as chaining in java.